# Changing report parameters intermittently causes loading screen to appear for minutes at a time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I'm using SQL Server and SSRS 2012. Intermittently when running reports on live environments, changing a single
 parameter can cause the entire report to lock up, show the loading icon, and not allow other parameter changes for minutes at a time.

I found a similar [ticket on microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/605780/ssrs-2008-r2-parameters-slow-response) that said it was fixed in a cumulative update for 2008 R2, but I'm experiencing it in SSRS 2012. I'm not sure what to do. Because it's intermittent, it's difficult to replicate, and I haven't been able to find any solutions for this online.

EDIT: This is only when changing the parameter, the loading occurs before I get the chance to hit 'View Report.' It can occur with several of the parameters, and most of them have dependencies. It can be on the parent or the child parameter.

I have also checked the execution log - the time taken to retrieve and process the parameters from shared data sets is much less than the time the 'loading' box stays on the screen. Max data retrieval time is 20secs total, loading box lasts for minutes at a time.

Comment: Do you mean when you re-run the report after changing a parameter or just changing the parameter without hitting View Report?

Comment: Just changing the parameter without hitting View Report.

Comment: are your parameters dependent on each other?

Comment: Most of them. It can be both parent and child parameters that cause this issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you re-run the report after changing a parameter or just changing the parameter without hitting View Report? If you are just changing the parameter, is the parameter used to refrsh othr related parameters? Basically we need to determine if the issue is with a query that's executing.

If it is then it could be a parameter sniffing issue where the query optimizer has used previous parameters to build a query plan that it not suitable. You can test this quickly by adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the affected dataset query (assuming it's just a SQL script).

Comment: This is only when changing the parameter, the loading occurs before I get the chance to hit 'View Report.' It can occur with several of the parameters, and most of them have dependencies. It can be on the parent or the child parameter.
I have also checked the execution log - the time taken to retrieve and process the parameters from shared data sets is much less than the time the 'loading' box stays on the screen. Max data retrieval time is 20secs total, loading box lasts for minutes at a time.

Comment: Without knowing more its tricky to say but if they have dependencies, that that's the most likely cause. When you change the parameter, it's querying the database  to populate the dependent parameters and that query may not be optimised. Try my suggestion above just as a test.

Comment: Sorry, just read your additional comments. I'm not sure I can be of any help in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance :)